# Location Update example for Android not working

Tags: android, geolocation, runtimeexception

[image]
I am trying location update example from following link

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#AppPermissions

It gave me some errors that I resolved by adding google play services, the application is building without errors, but when I am running it (both using AVD or real device) it is giving ClassNotFoundException and is not working.

I am using eclipse and ADT for my development

Adding error snapshot for reference

Comment: If you are on the R22 version of the development tools, be sure to fix up your projects' build paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22/16596990#16596990

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, then.

Comment: Same problem. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the lib `android-support-v4.jar` that is is your sdk.
Then, go to `project properties (alt+Enter) -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and then check android-support-v4.jar. Clean the project and it will work.

If you don't know how to ass a library you can co to properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab and then click to `add external jars`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should right-click on the Android project, choose properties, Java Build Path, and Checks the "Android Private Libraries" under "Order and Export".

You should tick something ;)

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893779/unable-to-resolve-superclass-of-lcom-worklight-androidgap-wldroidgap)

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the Google-play-services.jar file and also please make sure you have this metadata included in your manifest

for more details - refer

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html